# What does the 'n' in nLockTime and nSequence stand for?

Tags: locktime, sequence

I know what nLockTime and nSequence do, but I'm just curious about where the 'n' comes from. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It stand for a number, it is commonly used in programming to designate a variable that gonna hold an amount of something see: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/NLockTime and https://en.bitcoinwiki.org/wiki/NSequence

Comment: The concept of prefixing variable names with information about their type is called Hungarian notation. It was common in Windows programming in the '90s, and now is generally considered a bad idea.